# Show that $\mathbb{Z}[\pi]$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Assuming $\pi$ is not the root of any integer polynomial, show that $\mathbb{Z}[\pi]$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.

Is it valid to say that since $\pi$ is transcendental and since $\pi$ is not an integer that $\mathbb{Z}[\pi]$ will not add anything to $\mathbb{Z}[x]$? How can I say this more formally?

Answer (score 3):

To expand on your comment in Robert's hint/answer.

Yes, define $\varphi : \mathbb{Z}[x] \to \mathbb{R}$ by $\varphi(f(x))=f(\pi)$.

This is an "evaluation homomorphism". Obviously, $\varphi(f+g)=\varphi(f)+\varphi(g)$, $\varphi(fg)=\varphi(f)\varphi(g)$, $\varphi(1)=1$ (it is a homomorphism).

Notice that (essentially by definition) the image of $\varphi$ is $\mathbb{Z}[\pi]$.

Finally, for the kernel, suppose that $\varphi(f(x))=0$. This means that $f(\pi)=0$. But we know that $\pi$ is transcendental and so is not the root of any *nonzero* polynomial with integer coefficients. Therefore, $f(x)=0$. This shows the kernel is trivial.

Therefore, the domain is isomorphic to the image and you get $\mathbb{Z}[x] \cong \mathbb{Z}[\pi]$.

There's nothing really special about the integers and $\pi$ here. In general, you have $R[x] \cong R[\alpha]$ if $\alpha$ transcends $R$. In fact, that's essentially the definition of transcendental.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: consider the obvious mapping of $\mathbb Z[x]$ to $\mathbb Z[\pi]$.

Comment: So if i take the map from ℤ[x]to ℤ[π] defined by x-->π. Then I know that x-π=0, but this is false since π is transcendental. So then the kernel must just be equal to zero. So this is just the trivial map so therefore the two are equal????

Comment: No,, $x - \pi \ne 0$.  But it is true that the kernel is $0$.